# How to search the particular character in one word in asterisk server?

Tags: asterisk

How to search the particular character in given sentence in asterisk server?

Ex:-

word="test"

here

word - variable name

test - value of the variable

I want to search the 'e' character is present or not in given "test" value in asterisk server.

Is the any inbuilt command in asterisk server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REGEX function returns 1 if data matches regular expression or 0 otherwise.

So,

exten => s,n,Set(foo=${REGEX("[e]" ${word})})

The foo returns the "1" because the letter "e" matched